# Unable to validate form using unobtrusive js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple form for registration but unable to fire client side validation

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "register_form" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control text-input", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.FirstName) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control text-input", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Email) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control text-input", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword), type = "password" })
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control text-input", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LastName) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control text-input", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Password), type = "password" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline terms-text">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">I Agree with Terms &
                        Condition
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 btn-div">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit" onclick="Signup()">Register</button>
                    <button type="clear" class="btn btn-default btn-submit" onclick="return clearForm()">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

[image]

I can see all the js file is also render.

Even i have enable the clientsidevalidation and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in web.config.

Even from Controller side (ServerSide) unable to get errors.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Register")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(User model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                UserRepository contex = new UserRepository();
                contex.Register(model);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return View("SignUp", model);
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I really didn't getting what am I missing.

User Class

```
public sealed class User
 {
     #region Properties

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets the UserID value.
     /// </summary>
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets the EmailAddress value.
     /// </summary>
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address required")]
     [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                      @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                      @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                      ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
     [Display(Name = "Email")]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Email address ")]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets the Password value.
     /// </summary>
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password required")]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "*")]
     public string Password { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets the Confirm Password value.
     /// </summary>
     [Required]
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "*")]
     [Compare("Password")]
     public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     ///  Gets or sets of FirstName
     /// </summary>
     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets of LastName
     /// </summary>
     [Required]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
     /// Gets or sets the IsActive value.
     /// </summary>
     public bool? IsActive { get; set; }


     #endregion
 }
```

Signup Function

```
function Signup() {
        var $form = $('#register_form');
        var result =$form.valid();
        if (result) {

            debugger
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Account/Register',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    AjaxCallError(jqXHR, exception);
                },

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see that you're adding `Signup()` function to handle submit button click event, can you provide it in the question? Does it contain `$('form').valid()`?

Comment: Would it be possible to put up the User class so we can see what attributes you have set to validate the properties?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes i have checked that but all the time i got true for the valid() function

Comment: @JonRyan I have put User class.

Comment: Try adding `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);` before calling `$form.valid()` inside `Signup` function. Is this solve your problem?

Comment: What happens if you just use a standard submit button and don’t post the form with Ajax?

Comment: Also I remind you to use `$form.submit()` after checking validation instead of AJAX call because your controller uses `return View()` which will return entire view page. Also `preventDefault()` (with `return false`) may be necessary if the `onclick` trigger doesn't work.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto using $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form); It is directly go to server side when i am using form submit

Comment: I am still not able to do client side validation

Comment: Is that submit button triggered server-side submission immediately after clicking it (without passing `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form)`)? I think you should prevent default behavior of that button before client-side validation kicks in, if the form passes validation then submit to server.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes this is worked i have to stop it and need to use lower jquery version

Comment: How you managed to get that worked, using `preventDefault()` or something else? You may self-answer this problem with your own solution.